# Hide android application in long-press-HOME-button-menu

Tags: android, hide, history, taskmanager

I want to hide my android app from (and only from) the menu that appears when long holding the HOME-button after it is finished. Is there a way to do that? Calling finish() programatically dont do the trick.

There are many threads about hiding an app from the launcher and taskmanager, but this is not what I want, I simply dont want it to show up in this "app history".

best regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 10):

Add `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` to any `<activity>` element in the manifest for any activity that should not appear in the recent tasks list.

Comment: Used this solution to avoid user from re-entering a from-notification-only activity. Seems to be the only thing doing the trick, thanks!

Comment: @commonsware: How to clear recents list while long-pressing home button ?

Comment: @Sebastian, you should accept this answer. Works like a charm. The only problem is when long-pressing the home button while STILL in the app. My Nexus 5 still shows it in recents, but it's a broken link -- as if the recents were deleted right after rendering the recents table. Probably an android bug.